# To track clicks on a div using google analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, onclick

I have multiple DIVs with unique IDs. Each DIV onclick slides down and shows some content  below it.

I would like to track the clicks on each DIV to know which DIV is being clicked the most.

How do I do this with google analytics?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for Google Analytics "Event Tracking." Assuming you already have your regular GA code snippet set up (to track your site), you can then set up a handler (for clicks of the div, let's say) do to something like this with jQuery:

```
$('.trackerClass').click(function() {

  var selId = $(this).attr('id');

  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Interactions', 'Click', selId]);

});
```

Every div that you wanted to track could have both "trackerClass" as the class, and a unique ID to help you identify it.

If you wanted to track opens/closes individually, you could add a state variable and pass that as well.

More information is available here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking

**Edit**: for straight JavaScript, kennis' answer will do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I already have a GA code snippet set up. I have set up something like this `<div onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Interactions', 'Click', 'IDofDIV']);"></div>` But I am not able to see the click tracking details on my GA account.

Comment: @LINGS: Are there any errors in your browser's development console? Also, keep in mind that there can be a delay before new data shows up in GA

Answer (score 5):

Check out the GA page on Event Tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

The basic idea is:

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById('someDiv');
someDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'someDiv', 'click']);
}, false);
```