# Google Analytics not tracking pages

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

So i'm using GA to track the pages my users visit. Unfortunately, it's only giving me the main page back. I definitely have more than one page on my website.

I think it's because i'm using React (and only have 1 index.html file) but i'm not sure how to fix this. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is attach google analytics to DIV's and other things. What i suggest is to attach GA to other parts of your apps for better tracking

Please see this S.O. question for attaching to a div: [To track clicks on a div using google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198869/to-track-clicks-on-a-div-using-google-analytics)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GTM installed on your website it's possible to use a [History change](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en) tag that  has been created for such cases.

It fires every time an URL changes, even if a page doesn't reload completely. So that every time a user visits a new page (with new URL), this tag will send a pageview to GA.

Answer (score 0):

if your site is single page application then you will run into this case. You will have to detect the page change by some callbacks and then trigger page view manually. Uladislau Khatskevich thought is correct history change event can be used for it, if GTM is used. History change event will help you in detecting when the page is changed. If GTM is not used then you have to provide a callback when page change